# Azure IOT HUB Message routing tags with spaces or dot

Tags: azure, routes, message, azure-iot-hub

My IOT hub receives telemetry message from kepserver in the format

```
    {
    "CNC-Model_Performance.CNC-Model_KPI-Prameters.Station_Idle":false,
    "CNC-Model_Performance.CNC-Model_KPI-Prameters.Ideal_Cycle_time":120,
    "CNC-Model_Parameters.CNC-Model_Prameters-Alarms.Alarms.SPINDLE MPCB TRIPPED":false,
    "CNC-Model_Parameters.CNC-Model_Prameters-Alarms.Parameters.Coolant Temperature":0,
    "CNC-Model_Parameters.CNC-Model_Prameters-Alarms.Alarms.Hydraulic Motor   Current is High":false,
    "CNC-Model_Parameters.CNC-Model_Prameters-Alarms.Parameters.Incoming Voltage":0
    }
```

I need to route the data to a service bus  if the SPINDLE MPCB TRIPPED  is true or Hydraulic Motor current is High is true.
I am not able to put the correct route syntax as the tags has dot and spaces present and i am not able to override them . So  putting a condition like this
`$body.CNC-Model_Parameters.CNC-Model_Prameters-Alarms.Alarms.SPINDLE MPCB TRIPPED = true` is not working .
Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried something like `$body["CNC-Model_Parameters.CNC-Model_Prameters-Alarms.Alarms.SPINDLE MPCB TRIPPED"] = true`

Comment: Yes getting syntax error when validating.

Answer (score 1):

Routing message on the body with a *'.'* and/or *space* in its property names is not supported in the Azure IoT Hub, see already reported [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47655).

Please, write the feedback to the [Azure IoT team](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot-hub-dps-sdks).